# sending multiple requests with different value in sametime

Tags: asynchronous, post, python-requests, python-multithreading

```
requests.post("abc.com", data=payload1)
requests.post("abc.com", data=payload2)
requests.post("abc.com", data=payload3)
requests.post("abc.com", data=payload4)
```

What is the fastest way to send these four requests at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

One common way to do multiple things simultaneously is using threads they run independent of each other.

```py
import requests
import threading

def post_req(url, payload):
    print(requests.post(url, payload))

threading.Thread(target=post_req, args=("abc.com", payload)).start()
threading.Thread(target=post_req, args=("abc.com", payload)).start()
threading.Thread(target=post_req, args=("abc.com", payload)).start()
```